# how unpack tuple for wrapper function parameter in c++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples

```
//function wapper
template<class F,typename...Args>
class FuncWrapper
{
private:
    //F return type
    using return_type = typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type;

    template<int ...S> struct IndexSeq {};
    template<int N, int ...S> struct makeSeq : makeSeq<N - 1, N - 1, S...> {};
    template<int ...S> struct makeSeq<0, S...> : IndexSeq<S...> {};


public:
    FuncWrapper(F &&func,Args&&...args):
        f(std::move(std::function<return_type(Args...)>(std::forward<F>(func)))),
        para(std::make_tuple<Args...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
    {}
    ~FuncWrapper() = default;

    template <int... INDEX>
    return_type delay_action(makeSeq<INDEX...>)
    {
        return f(std::get<INDEX>(para)...);
    }

    //
    return_type operator()()
    {
        return  delay_action(makeSeq<sizeof...(Args)>{});
    }

private:
    //function
    std::function<return_type(Args...)> f;
    //parameter in the tuple
    std::tuple<Args...> para;
};

template<class F,typename ...Args>
FuncWrapper<F,Args...> make_function_wapper(F &&f, Args&&...args)
{
    return FuncWrapper<F, Args...>(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

here is the question : I want to create an template class for wrapper function , and use tuple for the parameter store , but it seems that it will not work well and I cannot find why. 
    so I need some help and who can explain for it . thx for your help !

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use C++14's [`index_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) instead of your own `IndexSeq`?

Comment: @JonathanWakely: probably because it is tagged C++11 (and repeated in title).

Comment: @Jarod42, but you can still use `integer_sequence` in C++11, e.g. [integer_seq.h](https://gitlab.com/redistd/integer_seq/blob/master/integer_seq.h). That would be "forward-compatible" rather than re-inventing the wheel, with different spelling.

Comment: thanks for all of your help  and I have already see what you talk about and didn't known them before .

Answer (score 1):

The below code:

```
template <int... INDEX>
return_type delay_action(makeSeq<INDEX...>)
{
    return f(std::get<INDEX>(para)...);
}
```

should be:

```
template <int... INDEX>
return_type delay_action(IndexSeq<INDEX...>)
//                       ~~~~~~~^
{
    return f(std::get<INDEX>(para)...);
}
```

The idea behind the sequence generator that you use is that the most-derived `makeSeq<2>` class eventually inherits from `IndexSeq<0, 1>`, and what you want to be deduced is the series of numbers from `IndexSeq`, not the length of a sequence from `makeSeq` itself.

You should also note that `Args` in `FuncWrapper` can be of a (possibly cv-qualified) lvalue reference type, so to safely store the arguments in a tuple, the tuple declaration should be as follows:

```
std::tuple<typename std::decay<Args>::type...> para;
//                  ~~~~~~~~~^
```

Comment: An other concern is what is the expected behavior for function like `void foo(std::unique_ptr<T>)`.

Comment: @Jarod42   Thank you for reminding, and I was just make a practice and not have a deep consideration about it .